# badly need help on how to code this on VBA

Tags: excel, vba, is-empty

badly need help on how to code this on VBA... excel column C: date borrowed, col E: status, col F: date returned. i need to automatically fill the status (Out or In). Out if col C is filled but col F is blank. then it will automatically update to "In" if col F is filled.

i have tried to use the isempty but cant seem to link it when the value of date borrowed is already filled.

Comment: Why don't you do this with a formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

`= IF(C2<>"",IF(F2="","Out","In"),"")`

If Date borrowed (C) is not empty, then the formula checks for Date returned (F): if empty then "out" else "in".

A VBA solution could look like this:

```vb
Public Function getStatus(dateBorrowed As Date, dateReturned As Date) As String
If dateBorrowed > 0 Then
    If dateReturned > 0 Then
        getStatus = "In"
    Else
        getStatus = "Out"
    End If
End If
End Function
```

You would call it `getStatus(activesheet.range("C2"), activesheet.range("F2"))`

Comment: i've tried these. but nothing works.

'Auto update of status on column D status

'Private Sub HHRMSdata_Change()
'If dateentry.Value > 1 And dateentry2.Value = Null Then
    'Range("D").Value = "Out"
'ElseIf dateentry.Value > 1 And dateentry2.Value > 1 Then
    'Range("D").Value = "In"
'Else
    'Range("D").Value = Null
'End If
'End Sub

Comment: 'Public Function getStatus(dateentry As Date, dateentry2 As Date) As String
'getStatus(HHRMSdata.Range("C"), HHRMSdata.Range("F")) = "D"

'If dateentry > 0 Then
'    If dateentry2 > 0 Then
'        getStatus = "Out"
'    Else
'        getStatus = "In"
'    End If
'End If
'End Function

Comment: Private Sub HHRMSdata_Change()
getStatus(HHRMSdata.Range("C"), HHRMSdata.Range("F")) = "D"
If IsEmpty(Range("C").Value) = False Then
    If IsEmpty(Range("F").Value) = False Then
        getStatus = "Out"
    Else
        getStatus = "In"
    End If
End If
End Sub